# About the universal morphism from the pushout of monomorphisms.

Tags: category-theory, universal-property, pushforward, monomorphisms

Let $A,B,C$ be objects in a category $\mathrm{C}$ and we have the pushout diagram of monomorphisms$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C @>>> A\\
@VVV @VVV\\
B @>>> A\bigsqcup\limits_C B\end{CD} Now consider another object $X$ in $\mathrm{C}$ such that the below diagram is a pullback square of monomorphisms. \begin{CD}
C @>>> A\\
@VVV @VVV\\
B @>>> X\end{CD}That is $C=A\times_XB$.
What conditions are necessary on the category $\mathrm{C}$ so that the universal morphism from the pushout $A\bigsqcup\limits_CB\to X$ is a monomorphism?

Comment: Are you assuming that $C \to B$ and $C \to A$ are the same morphisms in the two diagrams ? Because this is not true in general, so that the pushout $A \sqcup_C B \to X$ does not exist in general.

Comment: Very importantly, $A\cup B$ is a subobject of $X$ if you live in an Abelian category. Some subtleties can arise from the fact this is not necessarily true if you take infinite unions

Comment: @NaNoS Yes, the morphisms $C\to A$  and $C\to B$ are the same monomorphisms.

Comment: Did you read https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437194 ?

Comment: @JonasLinssen That was what I was looking for. Thank you.